# Permission denied in unprivileged docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rethinkdb, docker-image

I am trying to run a rethinkdb image on a Kubernetes cluster that has tight security measures and we must run containers as non-root, therefore I am using user 1000 to run them and I changed the Dockerfile to below:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update && apt install -y wget libcurl4 libprotobuf10 python3-pip

RUN wget https://github.com/srh/rethinkdb/releases/download/v2.3.6.srh.1/rethinkdb_2.3.6.srh.1.0bionic_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i rethinkdb_2.3.6.srh.1.0bionic_amd64.deb

ADD rethinkdb_tables /opt/rethinkdb_tables
RUN pip3 install rethinkdb==2.3

ADD entry_point.sh /opt/entry_point.sh

ENV RUN_ENV docker-compose

RUN id
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo
RUN groupadd newuser
RUN useradd -u 1000 -m -g newuser newuser
RUN adduser newuser sudo
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
RUN mkdir /data
RUN chown -R newuser:0 /opt/
RUN chown -R newuser:0 /data
USER newuser

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/opt/entry_point.sh" ]
CMD []
```

The entry_point.sh is a small script that starts the rethinkdb and as soon as the rethinkdb is up it imports some tables. But I am getting below error:

```sh
Launch rethinkdb in Kubernetes
Could not create directory 'rethinkdb_data': Permission denied
```

How I can fix this? I have to mention that this is the way that I used to run my other images as non-root and this worked for them.

Comment: What directory is the application actually running in?  What are its permissions and ownership?  The actual contents of the `entry_point.sh` script could be relevant to the question.

Comment: Could you please share both `rethinkdb_tables` and `entry_point.sh` files?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `entry_point.sh` because as I mentioned it just launches the rethinkdb and then it imports some tables. The problem was rethinkdb wanted to create the `rethinkdb_data` at `/` and I solved it by creating it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the rethinkdb wanted to create the `rethinkdb_data` at `/` I decided to create that directory myself in the Dockerfile and change its owner so rethinkdb can access it and this solved my problem.

Comment: Nice. You could fix that.